# Yet another 'member declaration not found'

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

It has been a while since I have written any C++, I am just trying to make a simple program replicating different types of clocks to refresh my memory.

I have begun by writing a `Clock` superclass and have gotten a `Member declaration not found` for each method other than my constructors/destructor. I presume it's a small error somewhere, but I can't spot anything.

**Clock.h**

```
/*
 * Clock.h
 */

#ifndef CLOCK_H_
#define CLOCK_H_

class Clock {
private:
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hours;

public:
    Clock();
    Clock(int, int, int);
    virtual ~Clock();
    virtual void tick() = 0;
    void setTime(int, int, int);
    void print();
};

#endif /* CLOCK_H_ */
```

**Clock.cpp**

```
/*
* Clock.cpp
 */

#include "Clock.h"
#include <iostream>

Clock::Clock() {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
}

Clock::Clock(int secs, int mins, int hrs) :
        seconds(secs), minutes(mins), hours(hrs) {
}

Clock::~Clock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

Clock::setTime(int secs, int mins, int hrs) {
    seconds = secs;
    minutes = mins;
    hours = hrs;
}

Clock::print() {
    std::cout << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error message is a bit longer and it would help seeing it as a whole.
That being said, the error could be due to the fact that your definition should be:

```
void Clock::setTime(int secs, int mins, int hrs) { /* ... */ }
```

Instead of:

```
Clock::setTime(int secs, int mins, int hrs) { /* ... */ }
```

That is, return type is missed in your case.
The same applies for `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Your return types for the following methods are missing in the implementation file (Clock.cpp).

```
Clock::setTime(int secs, int mins, int hrs) {
    seconds = secs;
    minutes = mins;
    hours = hrs;
}

Clock::print() {
    std::cout << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << std::endl;
}
```

which should be

```
void Clock::setTime(int secs, int mins, int hrs) {
    seconds = secs;
    minutes = mins;
    hours = hrs;
}

void Clock::print() {
    std::cout << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << std::endl;
}
```